# how to select one element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am experimenting with a different kind of review system for my application. I have 5 radiobuttons with values 1 to 5, and every value represent a color.

If a user is going to review the movie "Batman: the dark knight", it would look something like this:

[image]

When a user clicks on a value, it changes the background-color. I am using jQuery to control this.

**What the problem is:** The user should only be able to choose one value and that only that value should change background-color, right now you change click any value and it change its background-color.

*How can I do that in jQuery, any tips or ideas are welcome!*

Here is a exempel in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/puWJZ/

**HTML:**

```
<label class="input-check ch1">
 <input id="#rb1" type="radio" value="1"   name="reviewbutton" /> Bad
</label>
<label class="input-check ch2">
 <input id="#rb2" type="radio" value="2"   name="reviewbutton" /> Acceptable
</label>
<label class="input-check ch3">
 <input id="#rb3" type="radio" value="3"   name="reviewbutton" /> Good
</label>
<label class="input-check ch4">
 <input id="#rb4" type="radio" value="4"   name="reviewbutton" /> Very good
</label>
<label class="input-check ch5">
 <input id="#rb5" type="radio" value="5"   name="reviewbutton" /> Excellent
</label>
<div class="box">POP UP!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-check {
    display: block;
    height:20px;
    padding:10px;
    width:90px;
    color:#EEEEEE;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    display:none;
}
.ch1:hover{background-color: #ba0012; cursor: pointer;}
.ch2:hover{background-color: #ba0099; cursor: pointer;}
.ch3:hover{background-color: #00ba88; cursor: pointer;}
.ch4:hover{background-color: #0bbdf0; cursor: pointer;}
.ch5:hover{background-color: #f0b10b; cursor: pointer;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').hide();
    /* Bad */
    $('.ch1').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#ba0012'});
        $('.box').show();
    });
    /* Acceptable */
    $('.ch2').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#ba0099'});
        $('.box').show();
    });
    /* Good */
    $('.ch3').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#00ba88'});
        $('.box').show();
    });
    /* Very good */
    $('.ch4').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#0bbdf0'});
        $('.box').show();
    });
    /* Excellent */
    $('.ch5').click(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#f0b10b'});
        $('.box').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would completely remove the inline CSS and toggle a class on your buttons instead. You already have all the css colors in your `:hover` styles, simply adding selectors to include an `active` class would make it a lot cleaner as it is much simpler removing a class than it is storing and reverting inline css

CSS sample

```
.ch1:hover, .ch1.selected {background-color: #ba0012; cursor: pointer;}
```

JS to change class:

```
$('.input-check').click(function(){
   $('.input-check.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');

     /* other code when clicked*/
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: You solution look great and its very clean! Thank you.

Comment: changing class is always first line of thinking vs inline css. Is much simpler as you can see and leads to less problems in complicated apps. It keeps separation between style and logic

Answer (score 2):

To reset the colors for the rest of the elements, just prepend:

```
$('.input-check').css('background-color',"");
```

to all your event handlers.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/puWJZ/1/

Alternatively, you could add this event listener to the end of your code:

```
$('.input-check').click(function(){
    $('.input-check').not(this).css('background-color',"");
});
```

Here is a demonstration of the alternate approach: http://jsfiddle.net/puWJZ/3/

Comment: I like you solution, but when I save the review it dosent save the value.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake If by `saving` you mean a form submission, no JS solution can do that, you have to use a server side language.

Comment: No I dont mean form submission.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake How do you save a value then? There isn't really anything related to this in the example.

Comment: I am using rails, throw a rails form and it workt with my example. here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/6603c2ff1f5d90ddfe52

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like the way that you are doing it, you don't need to create a function for each label. But I think that what you want to do is use the [jQuery `not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) Let me propose you a better way to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myColors=new Array('#ba0012', '#ba0099', '#00ba88', '#0bbdf0', '#f0b10b');
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.input-check').click(function(){        
        $(this).css({'background-color' : myColors[$('.input-check').index($(this))]});
        $('.input-check').not($(this)).css({'background-color' : ''});
        $('.box').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/puWJZ/7/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the other answers, definitely go with one piece of code to handle the click event for all the buttons. Here I have added the **bgcolor** as a custom attribute to each radio button:

```
<input id="#rb1" type="radio" value="1"   name="reviewbutton" bgcolor="#ba0012"/> Bad
```

I have also added a class on all the input labels:

```
<label class="input-check ch1 rating_item">
```

We then check for a click on any of these elements, get the bgbolor from the custom attributed and set it on the clicked element (and reset all other elements)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').hide();
    $('.rating_item').click(function(){
        $('.rating_item').each(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color","#333333");
        });
        var this_bg_color = $(this).children().attr("bgcolor");
        $(this).css('background-color',this_bg_color);
        $('.box').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UxyWq/3/

Comment: I'm guessing you commented without even reading the code, it is a custom attribute, nothing to do with css

Comment: better use would be `data-bgcolor` but `bgcolor` is a property also that is being deprecated

Comment: yes, bgcolor was a poor choice for the attribute name nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic way of changing all the other colours back to their original colours.

`$('.ch2, .ch3, .ch4, .ch5').css({'background-color' : '#333'});`

http://jsfiddle.net/puWJZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

Mark labels using classes and set that classes same as in hover css

css:

```
.ch1:hover,.ch1.checked{background-color: #ba0012; cursor: pointer;}
.ch2:hover,.ch2.checked{background-color: #ba0099; cursor: pointer;}
.ch3:hover,.ch3.checked{background-color: #00ba88; cursor: pointer;}
.ch4:hover,.ch4.checked{background-color: #0bbdf0; cursor: pointer;}
.ch5:hover,.ch5.checked{background-color: #f0b10b; cursor: pointer;}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('label.input-check input').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('label.input-check').removeClass('checked');
        //the reason for next string it is just to make same code compatible with checkboxes
        //if not needed it ok to set $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
        $('label.input-check input:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
    });
    $('label.input-check').click(function(e) {
        var $t = $(this);
        if ($t.attr('type') == 'radio') {
            return true;
        }
        $t.children().first().click();
    });
});​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/puWJZ/13/)

---

other way to solve it is to make input same size as parent and set opacity to 0:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('label.input-check input').click(function(e) {
        $('label.input-check').removeClass('checked');
        //the reason for next string it is just to make same code compatible with checkboxes
        //if not needed it ok to set $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
        $('label.input-check input:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
    });

});​​
```

in css remove input and set this:

```
label.input-check input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.ch1:hover,.ch1.checked{background-color: #ba0012; cursor: pointer;}
.ch2:hover,.ch2.checked{background-color: #ba0099; cursor: pointer;}
.ch3:hover,.ch3.checked{background-color: #00ba88; cursor: pointer;}
.ch4:hover,.ch4.checked{background-color: #0bbdf0; cursor: pointer;}
.ch5:hover,.ch5.checked{background-color: #f0b10b; cursor: pointer;}
```

[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/puWJZ/14/)